# N combinations of words, simple bash

Tags: bash, text, combinations, text-processing

File 1:

```
1F
2F
3F
4F
5f
```

File 2:

```
1F
2F
3F
4F
5f
```

I have a simple code that produces all possible combinations

```
#!/bin/bash
    for a in $(awk '{print $1}' intf1) 
    do 
        for b in $(awk '{print $1}' intf2) 
        do 
            echo -e "$a:$b" >> file
        done 
    done
```

Output of this code:

```
1F:1F
1F:2F
1F:3F
1F:4F
2F:1F
etc
```

But I would like to:

1) Completely avoid repetitions

2) "Select the number" (the number of words (lines) which he will be taken from the second file):

Each two lines in second file:

```
1F:2F
1F:3F
2F:3F
2F:4F
3F:4F
3F:5F
4F:5F
```

Each three lines in second file:

```
 1F:2F
 1F:3F
 1F:4F
 2F:3F
 2F:4F
 2F:5F
etc..
```

And etc

Comment: what is your desired result? I don't understand request #2 and #3. I suggest making a smaller but full example

Comment: I have simplified text, too long text confuse people

Answer (score 0):

If the files could be sorted (and exclude repeating lines), this could work:

```
printf "%s\n" $(eval "echo {$(sort -u file.txt | paste -sd, -)}:{$(sort -u file2.txt | head -2 | paste -sd, -)}") | sort -u
```

It uses the bash expansion to generate the combinations, like:

```
$ echo {a,b}{X,Y,Z}
aX aY aZ bX bY bZ
```

also, you must ABSOLUTELY trust the content of the files, because the code uses dangerous `eval`.

The argument to `head` like `head -2` could be used for limiting the cound of lines from the `file2.txt`

The code produces (by limiting the second file to 2 already sorted lines) the following:

```
20160702F:20160702F
20160702F:20160714F
20160714F:20160702F
20160714F:20160714F
20160807F:20160702F
20160807F:20160714F
20160819F:20160702F
20160819F:20160714F
20160831F:20160702F
20160831F:20160714F
20160912F:20160702F
20160912F:20160714F
```